# how to avoid to use watchers in my controller?

Tags: angularjs

Ok i know that isn't a good practice to put a watcher inside a controller, but in this case how can i avoid to use watcher?

ps: $rootscope it's not a option ok?

here is the code:

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GJs808X7tsKZl11hOlme?p=preview)

**Edit - here what i did:**
[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gwm630khKzfUfFURjt4k?p=preview)

And here is the js code:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, mainService) {
  var flag = false;
  $scope.btn = function () {
    flag = !flag;
    mainService.setData(flag);  
  }
});

app.controller('DemoOneCtrl', function($scope, mainService) {
  $scope.name         = 'World';
  $scope.mainService  = mainService;
  $scope.show         = false;

  $scope.$watch('mainService.getData()', function (data) {
      $scope.show = data;  
  });
});

app.service('mainService', function () {
  var data = false;
  this.setData = function (str) {
    data = str; 
  };

  this.getData = function () {
    return data;  
  };
});
```

And html:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <button ng-click="btn()">GO!</button>
</div>
<div ng-controller="DemoOneCtrl">
    <p ng-show="show">Hello World</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It'd be better to add your code here, as that service may disappear at any moment in time.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to bind your `ng-show` to a service function.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, mainService) {
  var flag = false;
  $scope.btn = function () {
    flag = !flag;
    mainService.setData(flag);  
  }
});

app.controller('DemoOneCtrl', function($scope, mainService) {
  $scope.name         = 'World';
  $scope.mainService  = mainService;
  $scope.show         = mainService.getData;

});

app.service('mainService', function () {
  var data = false;
  this.setData = function (str) {
    data = str; 
  };

  this.getData = function () {
    return data;  
  };
});
```

Notice how `$scope.show` is set to `mainService.getData`.  Now you can bind `show()` to `ng-show`.

```
<p ng-show="show()">Hello World</p>
```

No `$watch` needed.

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/PNAXoUCqnkDlqXFlULDr?p=preview)

Comment: very good! i didn't know that, but it only resolved this case, i need another solution if it exist.